# phpunit expectException() wrong exception name

Tags: exception, phpunit, assertion, invalidargumentexception

When I run PHPUnit 6.5.13. and have a test method following this example [PHPUnit Testing Exceptions Documentation](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/7.4/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#testing-exceptions)

```
public function testSetRowNumberException()
{
    $this->expectException(\InvalidArgumentException::class);
    $result = $this->tableCell->setRowNumber('text');

}
```

that tests this method:

```
public function setRowNumber(int $number) : TableCell
{
    if (!is_int($number)) {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Input must be an int.');
    }
    $this->rowNumber = $number;

    return $this;
}
```

I got this failure:

> Failed asserting that exception of type "TypeError" matches expected exception "InvalidArgumentException".

the question is why `"TypeError"` is taken to assertion and how to make assertion use `InvalidArgumentException`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it. The thing is I used typing set to `int` that's why the code didn't even reach the thow command.

it works if tested method is without set typing to `int`:

```
public function setRowNumber($number) : TableCell
{
    if (!is_int($number)) {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Input must be an int.');
    }
    $this->rowNumber = $number;

    return $this;
}
```

or when the test has `TypeError`

```
public function testSetRowNumberException()
{
    $this->expectException(\TypeError::class);
    $result = $this->tableCell->setRowNumber('text');
}
```

I'll stay with the second example.